# Why when I want to run an Android yarn error like this?

Tags: react-native

Why when I want to run an Android yarn error like this?

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details
> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
10 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 8 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     D:\xampp\htdocs\konspirasiSnack\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-25:19: AAPT: error: resource m
ipmap/ic_launcher (aka com.konspirasisnack:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.

     D:\xampp\htdocs\konspirasiSnack\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-25:19: AAPT: error: resource s
tring/app_name (aka com.konspirasisnack:string/app_name) not found.

     D:\xampp\htdocs\konspirasiSnack\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-25:19: AAPT: error: resource m
ipmap/ic_launcher_round (aka com.konspirasisnack:mipmap/ic_launcher_round) not found.

     D:\xampp\htdocs\konspirasiSnack\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-25:19: AAPT: error: resource s
tyle/AppTheme (aka com.konspirasisnack:style/AppTheme) not found.

     D:\xampp\htdocs\konspirasiSnack\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:13:7-23:18: AAPT: error: resource 
string/app_name (aka com.konspirasisnack:string/app_name) not found.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. R
un with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 35s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnat
ive.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

react native versi 0.62.2
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.0.1-all.zip
os windows 10
java version "1.8.0_251"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)
ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk

Comment: The error says it all basically: `Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.` 
So please try --warning-mode all to get more info

Comment: I've tried it and still error

Comment: Sure, that should not solve the error but give a bit more information what needs to be done, maybe you can post the log with the flag?